# Highcharts pie chart loses color on refresh

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

highcharts: 8.0.4

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/clinsted/z4jftkcp) to demonstrate what is happening, showing a pie and bar chart and how they behave differently. In my scenario the chart is instantiated without data. Then data is requested from an api (simulate this in the jsfiddle by clicking the buttons). The charts display, then data is refreshed (click the buttons again). You should notice that the pie chart "disappears" while the bar chart does not. I would guess this is because the "color" property is set to null.

My question is why does the pie chart behave differently to the bar chart?

In my scenario I may or may not have a "color" value returned from the api. I did come up with a solution to conditionally add the property only if it has a value:

```
data.map((d) => {
  if (d.color) {
    return (
      {
        name: d.group,
        y: d.value,
        color: d.color,
        id: d.id,
      });
  }
  return (
    {
      name: d.group,
      y: d.value,
      id: d.id,
    });
});
```

This does seem to work, however (here is my second question), is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular use case:

1. You can use the update instead of the **setData** feature.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1bjfh63c/

Code:

```
button1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99)) + 1;
    let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (99)) + 1;
  chart1.series[0].setData(
        [{
            y: x,
        name: 'Apple',
        color: null,
        id: 1,
      },
      {
            y: y,
        name: 'Peach',
        color: null,
        id: 2,
      }
    ], false, false, false);

  chart1.redraw();
})
```

2. In setData set the **updatePoints** flag to false - that's why the error occurred.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/umo14be0/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData

Comment: I am marking the answer as correct, as it does solve my problem, thank you much appreciated. However it does not answer my first question, why do these 2 chart types behave differently?